# Implications of a singleton Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver

I was just thinking of making a single object of a thread i.e. a singleton so that I've made just a single Thread object in my entire application. 
It's job will be same whenever I call. I don't want to make the process run in the main application thread.

I also would like to synchronize the job (work done by runnable) if job is called from multiple locations.

Is it good this design will be and what can be the pros and cons of it ?

I actually will be calling the runnable's run from android receivers (I've couple of them) which will start a service and call the runnable.

Comment: The primary benefit of threads is that you can have more than one.  What advantage do you feel you will gain by constraining yourself to a single thread?

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't want to run your job in the same thread as the service. So, i wanted to make one thread which will run in a separate process. 

If the service is killed and re-started i would like to use the same thread i had created earlier and not re-create another one.

Comment: You can't use threads in a different process unless you use another  service or IPC / AIDL thing to communicate between your processes. Plus that other process could be killed as well. Just recreate the thread if one process dies. Also don't use a singleton `Thread` since a thread can only run once. Use a [`FixedThreadPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) with size 1 instead. Executors re-use a thread to run `Runnable`s

Comment: Actually, my thread is going to run indefinitely sleeping in between while executing jobs. My thread will send emails periodically based on content available. If i have multiple threads then each service invoked by the receiver will send email separately. I don't want that. I wan't each service to send the same email else wait. 

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: or am i missing something. As far as i understand, first receiver starts service and the service starts the thread (say i start a single thread); next receiver starts the same service ; since, the service is already running, it will directly call onStart() and execute run() method ..correct ? will this approach work ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a singleton thread is a recommended thing to do. If you want a thread instance that be running all the time and handle your requests so consider using [a HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) which is basically a thread with a Looper that keeps the thread running and waiting for your messages.

You do **not** override a `run()` method as in normal threads, you communicate with your thread by sending messages via the Handler object that is connected to the handlerThread looper. Here is an example:

Define and start your HandlerThread

```
 HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("My handler thread");
 handlerThread.start();
```

Create a handler associated with the handlerThread looper and override handleMessage

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    switch (msg.what) {
    case DO_SOMETHING:
        // do your logic
        break;

    case DO_ANOTHER_THING:
        // do your logic
         break;        
    }        
  }
}
```

Communicate with your thread send a message

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = DO_SOMETHING; // an arbitrary constant integer
// You can pass extra arguments in msg.arg1, msg.arg2 and msg.obj
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

When you are done remember to stop your handlerThread

```
handlerThread.quit();
```